# Identify convex function that may be non-convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I am having an issue with an assignment about function convexity. 
I understand the definitions of convexity but here I am tasked with first finding a function such that

$$ f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)  $$

is a convex increasing function but also such that $ (1/z)f(z)$ is non convex in $(0,\infty)$

I tried multiple convex functions that I know but I can't make them non convex as asked. Is there a trick to his?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with $f(z)=z^{3/2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=x^a$, with $a\in(1,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x \log x$ for $x >0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Then $f$ is convex
on $[0,\infty)$ but
since ${1 \over x} f(x) = \log x$, we see that $x \mapsto {1 \over x} f(x)$ is strictly concave on $(0,\infty)$.